# How to Open a PDF at a Named Destination

Tags: java, url, pdf

I need to write a Java program that opens a PDF file at a named destination.  The file test.pdf contains the named destination "DestinationX" on page 2.  The program opens the PDF file but does not go to the named destination.  How do I get to the named destination?

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
public class MyLauncher {
    static void openFileAtNamedDest(){
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            try {
                URI myURI = new URI("file:///C:/test.pdf#nameddest=DestinationX");
                Desktop.getDesktop().browse( myURI );
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        openFileAtNamedDest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [spec](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters_v9.pdf), the format of your URL is correct. The only question is what application you are actually launching via `browse()`. I think it acts the same way as if you had double-clicked the file's icon on your desktop: it will launch whatever application is registered as the default handler for PDFs.

Acrobat should be able to handle a URL with a named destination, but other PDF viewers may not support it.